# How to integrate Swiftmailer into Angular2

Tags: php, angular, swiftmailer

since i couldn't find an answer for three days now, I try to ask it myself.

I'm kinda new to Angular, started learning it 2 weeks ago. I set up a project with angular-cli. So far so good everything works as i imagined besides my contact form.

**What i want**
I want to integrate Swiftmailer into my Angular project, so I can actually send an e-mail *locally* (Linux Mint) to myself via contact form.

**What i have**
I already have a simple bootstrap form (name, e-mail, message) and I added [Swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com) via *composer*. I created a file named mail.php (because Angular can't do that) into my assets folder:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'../vendor/autoload.php';

$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.actual-server.de', 25))
->setUsername('actually-filled-in-working-username')
->setPassword('actually-filled-in-working-password')
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_AntiFloodPlugin(100, 30));

// Create a message
$message = (new Swift_Message('Test Subject'))
->setFrom([$request->email => $request->name])
->setTo(['suzu.amaranthine@gmail.com' => 'Suzu'])
->setBody($request->message)
;

// Send the message
return $mailer->send($message);
```

In my template I was setting the action to this file. When I try to submit, nothing happens. My idea was, that i need to do something in my contact.component.ts, but when I try to import "Swiftmailer/Message.php", I fail.

Does anyone have an idea what I need to do there to make it work together?

Versions:

```
PHP 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

"swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.0"

@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 6.11.1
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.0
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/common: 4.3.0
@angular/compiler: 4.3.0
@angular/core: 4.3.0
@angular/forms: 4.3.0
@angular/http: 4.3.0
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.0
@angular/router: 4.3.0
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.0
@angular/language-service: 4.3.0
```

Comment: You seem to be lacking basic form/POST knowledge before even learning a complicated frontend framework like Angular. You should make the distinction of frontend and backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, finally. I was missing a "/" when loading vendor/autoload.php , that's why it didn't work.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
```